# How to upload image to firebase storage using Golang

Tags: image, firebase, go, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I have been struggling for the past hours trying to upload an image to firestore storage but I can't make it... The image seems  to be corrupted once on Firestore

```
func (fs *FS) Upload(fileInput []byte, fileName string) error {

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), fs.defaultTransferTimeout)
    defer cancel()

    bucket, err := fs.client.DefaultBucket()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    object := bucket.Object(fileName)
    writer := object.NewWriter(ctx)
    defer writer.Close()

    if _, err := io.Copy(writer, bytes.NewReader(fileInput)); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if err := object.ACL().Set(context.Background(), storage.AllUsers, storage.RoleReader); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil

}
```

I get no error but once uploaded... I get this:

[image]

Meanwhile on Google Cloud Storage:

[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: From where you are getting the (fs *FS)

Comment: It’s a function of a struct :) fs is then the parent struct https://medium.com/rungo/anatomy-of-methods-in-go-f552aaa8ac4a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The upload is probably fine.  The Firebase console is just known to be unable to show previews of content that was not uploaded by a web or mobile client.  Try downloading the file locally to verify that it's the same as what you uploaded.

Feel free to also [file a feature request with Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) about the console.

Answer (score 2):

You need to send an additional metadata attribute: *firebaseStorageDownloadTokens*

Like:

```
    import (
        "github.com/google/uuid"
    )

    func (fs *FS) Upload(fileInput []byte, fileName string) error {

        //create an id
        id := uuid.New() 

        ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), fs.defaultTransferTimeout)
        defer cancel()
    
        bucket, err := fs.client.DefaultBucket()
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    
        object := bucket.Object(fileName)
        writer := object.NewWriter(ctx)

        //Set the attribute
        writer.ObjectAttrs.Metadata = map[string]string{"firebaseStorageDownloadTokens": id.String()} 
        defer writer.Close()
    
        if _, err := io.Copy(writer, bytes.NewReader(fileInput)); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    
        if err := object.ACL().Set(context.Background(), storage.AllUsers, storage.RoleReader); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    
        return nil
    
    }
```

The image should appear after these changes.